# RSA Encryption returns strange format

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I'm using RSACryptoServiceProvider to encrypt URL parameters values but I get the encryption result like the following

뙣湕ᯧ뿆埾怏禽每퉀ᓂд泅짙쟐쥌䃍萾雿ퟢ泛閣Ḇ見嘊䟧埰

is there any way to change the format to normal English format.

code sample :

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class RSACSPSample
{

    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a UnicodeEncoder to convert between byte array and string.
            UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();

            //Create byte arrays to hold original, encrypted, and decrypted data.
            byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes("string to Encrypt");
            byte[] encryptedData;
            byte[] decryptedData;

            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider to generate
            //public and private key data.
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {

                //Pass the data to ENCRYPT, the public key information 
                //(using RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false),
                //and a boolean flag specifying no OAEP padding.
                encryptedData = RSAEncrypt(dataToEncrypt, RSA.ExportParameters(false), false);

                //Pass the data to DECRYPT, the private key information 
                //(using RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(true),
                //and a boolean flag specifying no OAEP padding.
                decryptedData = RSADecrypt(encryptedData, RSA.ExportParameters(true), false);

                //Display the decrypted plaintext to the console. 
                Console.WriteLine("Decrypted plaintext: {0}", ByteConverter.GetString(encryptedData));
                Console.WriteLine("Decrypted plaintext: {0}", ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedData).Replace(2312423423.ToString(),""));
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            //Catch this exception in case the encryption did
            //not succeed.
            Console.WriteLine("Encryption failed.");
        }
    }

    public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] encryptedData;
            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {

                //Import the RSA Key information. This only needs
                //toinclude the public key information.
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

                //Encrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
                //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
                //later.  
                encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return encryptedData;
        }
        //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
        //to the console.
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            return null;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] decryptedData;
            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                //Import the RSA Key information. This needs
                //to include the private key information.
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

                //Decrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
                //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
                //later.  
                decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return decryptedData;
        }
        //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
        //to the console.
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just turn any old set of bits into UTF-16 -- Unicode encodings don't work that way. If you want to turn a set of bits into a human-readable string, encoder it as something like hex or base64

Comment: the result of encryption is just binary data and not meant to be printed. If you want a prinatable result or use it as a url parameter or similar, you need to base64(url) encode it.

Comment: [Base64UrlEncoder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.base64urlencoder?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: English is a human language. You can convert to **printable ASCII** using base 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting the `bytes[]` encrypted data change the conversion to:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText)
```

Comment: Please check my edits and always reread your answer before posting, now your ciphertext was a string instead of a byte array.